# Adding 3 days from Due date exclude weekend using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow

The workflow has to change the due date by adding 3 days to the due date. It has to also make sure to exclude the weekend and only add the 3 days based on business days.

If the due date is 11/23/2017, the workflow has to add 3 days to the due date , excluding the weekends. So for 11/23/2017 the due date should be 11/28/17.

Answer (score 2):

Take your due date and put it into a variable as a Long Date - that will start the string with Sunday, Monday..... in pseudocode:

```
If var:duedate starts with Wed
or var:duedate starts with Thurs
or var:duedate starts with Fri
     add 5 days to currentitem:duedate (output to var:newdate)
else if var:dueDate starts with Sat
     add 4 days to currentitem:duedate (output to var:newdate)
else
     add 3 days to currentitem:duedate (output to var:newdate)
set currentItem:duedate to var:newdate
```

Comment: I need to be able to take into account a federal holiday. So how to do that?

Comment: If you are using 2013 workflows you can call webservices. And I would expect you would be able to find a webservice that will return false or true if a date is a holiday. Based on that you could create your logic. That would be far easier than hardcoding holidays or manually maintain a list of holidays. I can see how you would be able to create a any logic that would handle all federal holidays.

Comment: Without having looked a lot at it, it would seem something like this would work: https://services.timeanddate.com/api/holiday-countries-listing.html

Comment: I did some more searching and found this API which - for free - does excatly what I suggested first: http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v1.0/?action=isPublicHoliday&date=05-07-2012&country=usa

Comment: Thanks Morten, How can I add the workflow to exclude the federal holiday? I need help please ? Thanks again